# iterm2 cannot toggle fullscreen when in 'top of screen' mode

Tags: macos, osx-lion, fullscreen, iterm, iterm2

I'm trying to toggle fullscreen in iTerm2 by pressing "cmd+enter".
Unfortunately it doesn't work when 'top of screen' style is selected in the profile settings (as shown in the attached png). When I press "cmd+enter", the 'view' tab in the menu flashes, but the window remains taking up half the screen instead of fullscreen.

Is it just not possible to switch between halfscreen and fullscreen?

[image: iTerm profile settings]

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a bug. I also am unable to go into full screen when switching the style to anything other than normal.

I also have a different version of iTerm than you from what I can tell. (Build 1.0.0.20130319)

[image: iterm settings]

Comment: I am seeing this behavior too on the same build you have (`Build 1.0.0.20130319`)

Comment: Looks like this is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=642) targeted for a future release.

Comment: It is fix in the current beta, and will be available in the future iterm3 (end 2015)  https://www.iterm2.com/downloads.html

Comment: This is fixed in iTerm3 Beta (my version is Build 2.9.20160206).

Answer (score 3):

Having '***Top of Screen***' selected indeed breaks the '*Cmd + Enter*' fullscreen capability, but I've noticed that having the `Preferences` > `General`: `Use Lion-style Fullscreen windows` option checked also does a trick on this functionality.

Once you uncheck this, you should be able to use any other style (*except the 'Top of Screen' one*), and benefit from a functional fullscreen feature ;)

Mac OS v10.10.3 
iTerm2 v2.1.1

Comment: Interesting. That must have gotten turned on by a recent update (2.1.1). If I turn off "Lion-style Fullscreen windows" there, then my Cmd-Tab works again to switch between applications.

Comment: This doesn't work in version 2.1.4 anymore.